# How should I use WAI-ARIA attributes to describe check boxes nested within radios?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

I am building a user interface where visitors to a web site are asked questions and must choose answers. The answers are sometimes complex enough that we have decided to use sets of radio buttons, with nested check boxes: each set of check boxes controlled by its radio button. (Much effort has gone into reducing the complexity, etc. and we've also considered other options like drop-downs with long, wordy answers. That's not what this question is about.)

With some JavaScript, we can fairly easily ensure that the relationship between the controls is visually clear. (Note that the following screen captures are mock-ups, and the graphical design is yet to come. The question and answers are also fictional.)

[image][image][image]
We need to ensure that we also offer the correct experience to people who are using assistive technologies such as a screen reader. I have looked at the various [WAI-ARIA attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#attrs_relationships) which can be used to enhance HTML to allow this. Below is the HTML I used to generate the screen captures.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            fieldset {width: 300px;}
            .pseudoDisabled {
            background-color: #f4f2f2;
            }
        </style>
    <script>
      $(function(){
        $("fieldset.question").each(function(){
        // if a radio is followed by a fieldset with the right owning-radio, the 
        // fieldset should join in with the radio-button logic 
        $(this).children("input").change(function(){
          if (this.checked){                    
           if($(this).nextAll("fieldset:first").attr("data-owning-radio") === this.id){
             $(this).siblings("fieldset").prop("readonly", false).removeClass("pseudoDisabled");
           } else {
             $(this).siblings("fieldset").prop("readonly", true).addClass("pseudoDisabled");
           }            
         }
       });
     });

     // Ensure that clicking on a nested checkbox activates the matching radio
     $("[data-owning-radio]").each(function(){
       var jThis = $(this);
       var owningRadio = jThis.attr("data-owning-radio");
       jThis.children("input").change(function(){
         $("#" + owningRadio).prop( "readonly", false ).removeClass("pseudoDisabled").prop("checked", true);
         });
         jThis.click(function(){
            $(this).prop("readonly", false).removeClass("pseudoDisabled");
          });
        });

        // We'd have liked to use 'disabled', but then you don't get click events, so 
        // instead we use readonly for the controls that we don't want to be successful
        // and switch to disabled as we submit.
        $("form").submit(function(e) {
        $("fieldset", this).filter(function(){
          return $(this).prop("readonly") == true
        }).prop("disabled", true);          
      });
    });
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <div>
        <fieldset name="question1" class="question">
          <legend>Do you pay tax?</legend>
          <input type="radio" name="oq1" id="oq1a1" value="no" />
          <label for="oq1a1">No</label><br />
          <input type="radio" name="oq1" id="oq1a2" value="yes" aria-controls="q1a2checkboxes"/>
          <label for="oq1a2">Yes</label><br />
          <fieldset id="q1a2checkboxes" name="q1a2checkboxes" data-owning-radio="oq1a2">
            <input type="checkbox" name="questiona2" id="oq2a2a" value="incomeTax" />      
            <label for="oq2a2a">I pay income tax</label><Br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="questiona2" id="oq2a2b" value="vat" />
            <label for="oq2a2b">I pay Value Added tax</label><Br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="questiona2" id="oq2a2c" value="local" />  
            <label for="oq2a2c">I pay local tax</label>
          </fieldset>       
        </fieldset>
      </div>
      <input type=submit>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I have used the [aria-controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-controls) attribute to indicate the relationship between the `radio` and the `fieldset` it controls. Is this the correct approach? Is it sufficient, or do I need also to use various other attributes to describe more detailed relationships?

So far my web searches have yielded mostly very abstract standards documents, and not much in the way of clear advice, so any good references would also be very welcome.

Comment: A `fieldset` within a `fieldset` sounds like a nightmare to me, and they need a `legend` to be meaningful. I would drop the nested `fieldset`, and add `aria-describedby="oq1a2"` to the `input`s. I *don't* think the [`aria-controls`](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-controls) is used correctly, but not 100% on that

Comment: As I said, the nested check boxes are necessary and much discussed in our team. If we're going to have them, grouping them in a fieldset seems correct to me, at least semantically.. And keeping the hierarchy prevents having go down the route of aria-owns, aria-level etc.

Comment: I did not look it up, but for a `fieldset` to be valid, it must have a `legend` associated. If you are concerned that the screen reader user won't know that they are together, don't worry. When checkboxes and radio buttons have the same `name` attribute, they are grouped together. The screen reader will say something to the effect of "I pay income tax radio 1 of 3 edit"